# how to get the background id of the button

Tags: android, button

I want to get the generated ID of the background image of my button.
That star image is from drawable; I want to get its generated ID.

I know `.getId` will get the particular ID of the button, but the ID of the background resource is what I want to get. There's no such thing as `button.getBackground().getId()`

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnhgfavorite"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/star" 
    android:focusable="false"/>
```

Comment: Could you please tell us, what exactly do you want to do with it?

Comment: i want this id for condition, if star is active it returns yes,if not no,. or how to cast this R.drawable.star into a Drawable type, its integer right?

Comment: I am sorry, I have no idea what you want to do. Could you try to make your intents more clear?

Comment: You should either accept an answer or "answer yourself" if you came up with the solution in order to close up this question ;)

Comment: @RoRo Have you found the answer? I need it.

Comment: unfortunately i haven't, i use the long method of doing my condition :(

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have the drawable itself stored in the Resources folder. Simply get the id from there:

```
int id = R.drawable.star;
```

and thats it!

If you want that background image as the system formatted it, you will not be able to do so, as the image is not saved when rescaled, because that is done "on the go".

For any complicated features and functions of Button, try either extending Button and creating your own, or simply use a different class.

Comment: no, i need to get all of those with its corresponding button, or to simplify if i click that button i wanted to get its corresponding background resource id

Comment: I do not think that there is such an id generated for background specifically for each button.

Comment: Do you need to change its background while pressing the button? Then you need to implement the background as selector

Comment: if you set a corresponding background onto button is button.setBackgroundResource(int id) right, so i want it reverse

Comment: i'm using that id for condition statements

Comment: That seems way too complicated and I don't really think that Button will serve you well in this case. Have you considered using different classes?

Answer (score 0):

I also have this issue.but I hava idea.you can custom a button. and creat a variable  in it.then you can use get(), set() method to  operate the image's id.

```
class MyButton extend button{
    int id = R.id.imageId;
    public int getID(){
      returen id;
    }
    public void setID(int id){
      this.id = id;    
    }
}
```

but i don't think it's a good way.if you have a good way to solve it.please tell me.